# Can not find DbUpdateConcurrencyException Entries.Single() method in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am following Tom Dykstra's "Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5" tutorial.
In concurrency handling part, I can not use the Single() method at Entries. It says-

> "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumarable does not contain a definition for 'Single' and no extension method 'Single' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumarable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly referrence?)"

Here is the code-

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ContosoUniversity.DAL;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

//...

catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
     var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
     var clientValues = (Department)entry.Entity();
     var databaseEntry = entry.GetDatabaseValues();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `using  System.Linq`

[Enumerable.Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has the namespace `System.Linq`